# Why does my MVC dropdownlist have a value selected despite the property value being NULL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdownlist where a user can select a care provider. In the database the value for this is `null` however in the application, a value is selected. What do I need to do to have the `null` value appear as a blank? I thought this was the default behavior. I changed to using strongly typed lists in my view model instead of the viewbag and this may have broken at that time.

Here is the view markup:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PsychologistId, "Psychologist")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PsychologistId, Model.ListPsychologists)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PsychologistId)
</div>
```

Here is the property from the view model:

```
 [DisplayName("Psychologist")]
 public Nullable<int> PsychologistId { get; set; }
```

Here is the relevant part of my controller:

```
    model.ListPsychologists = new SelectList(XXX, "Id", "DisplayName");

    return this.View(model);
```

where XXX is just the LINQ expression with filtering and sorting criteria. It's been omitted for clarity and space.

The model passed from the controller to the view has `PsychologistId` being `null`. And the `SelectedValue` property on `model.ListPsychologists` is `null`.

Comment: See my DDL tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

if PsychologistId is an int, it will assign 0 value to it since int is not a nullable type.

Show your model and controller if my assumption above is not true.

Comment: PsychologistId is a nullable type in his class.

Comment: Well, based on his original question we could not know this so this was a fine assumption. no reason to down vote it. Instead of down voting better give a valid solution

Comment: He did put the view model property code in the original post: public Nullable<int> PsychologistId { get; set; }

Comment: you haven't seen his original question... it didn't have it

Comment: Ah, I see, my bad.  If you add a whitespace character to your answer, it will let me change my vote.

Answer (score 0):

Does your SelectList contain entry with `Id==null`? I doubt that. And that means that you will have no select list entry matching your value, so browser will select first one available.

Solution: explicitly add entry with `Id = null` to your SelectList.

Answer (score 0):

I've had these issues before, and what I did to fix it was send the base collection of what I want to fill the dropdown with in the viewmodel, instead of a SelectList.  So:

```
model.ListPsychologists = XXX;
```

Then in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PsychologistId, new SelectList(Model.ListPsychologists, "Id", "DisplayName", Model.PsychologistId))
```

Please verify the SelectList constructor overload I used in MSDN, I'm typing this from memory.  Basically you give it the collection of items to use in the SelectList, then the name of the text and value properties (just like you did in your action method code), and the fourth parameter is the value to set the drop down to.

Edit: Also, there is an overload for the DropDownListFor to add a default item in the menu.  Like, "Select One".

Comment: I tried both of these suggestions. They build and the app runs but unfortunately the issue remains unresolved.

Comment: Doh!  You might want to make a code block in your view file and add a break point to it.  You can then verify all the data the view is receiving from the action method.  Maybe there is a discrepancy in the data somewhere.

Comment: I set a breakpoint in the view markup. The PsychologistId in the model is null and the SelectedValue on the list is null.

Comment: Have you verified that the list of Psychologists you are using to create the select list does not have an item with a null ID?

Comment: The list does not have an item with a null ID.